# why does React counter component print two times console.log?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I the next code I have this problem with Small component because always is print two time, even when the component is created first time

App.js

```
import { useCounter } from "../Hooks/useCounter";
import { Small } from "./Small";

export const Memorize = () => {
  const {counter, increment} = useCounter(10)

  return(
    <>
      <Small value={counter}/>
      <button
        onClick={event => increment()}>
        +1
      </button>
    </>
  )
}
```

useCounter.js
The counter value is working fine...

```
import { useState } from "react";

export const useCounter = (initialValue = 0) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(initialValue)

  const increment = (value = 1) => setCounter(counter + value)

  return {
    counter,
    increment,
    setCounter
  }
}
```

Small.js
... here the problem or I dont know...

```
export const Small = ({value}) => {
  console.log('Iam console log...');

  return (
    <small>{value}</small>
  )
}
```

... each time that I do click in button +1 this console is print:

```
Iam console log...
Iam console log...
```

... I try to envolve with memo but doesnt works...
any ideas ?

Comment: Probably because of the Strict Mode is on. Try remove `<StrictMode>` in index.js. but you should not use console log to measure performance of your components. Use a proper tool like React Profiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because of the Strict Mode is on. Try remove  in index.js.

When `<StrictMode>` is enabled the component will render two times, that's why its render two `console.log()`